# Gfortran compiler optimization flags similar to ifort in Intel

Tags: compiler-optimization, gnu, gfortran, intel-fortran, rocks

I am currently using ifort (Intel Fortran compiler). However, in the AMD cluster (which has AMD processors), it seems that Intel parallel studio can not be installed. Therefore I decided to use gfortran (GNU Fortran compiler) instead of ifort. In ifort, my compiler flags were
`ftn -heap-arrays -mcmodel=large -g -c` 
I want to know the similar optimization flags in the GNU compiler.
My GCC version is 4.4.7 in centos 6.6 and the rocks cluster version is 6.2.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832496/gfortran-flag-for-intels-heap-arrays-size) for `-heap-arrays`. `-g -c` is the same for both compilers. `-mcmodel=large` also appears to be the same for both. I wouldn't have described any of those flags as "optimization flags" exactly.

Comment: You will want to add the `-O` or `-O2` options at minimum with gfortran.